# This Entity Reference View Isn't Working Right

Tags: entities, views

Here's my situation:

I have a node type for "School" and node type for "Classroom." In the School node type, I have an Entity Reference field for "Classroom," and vice-versa (i.e. I have a "School" Entity Reference field in the Classroom node). I am using The Corresponding Entity Module to make sure everything's connected.

Further, in the Classroom node type, I have en Entity Reference field for "Teachers", which corresponds to users, and an integer field for # of students.

I am trying to create a view which would show me how many total classrooms, students, and teachers I have in each school.

I am able to get it working for the total number of classrooms and students. As soon as I add the "teachers" field into the view, though, my student count gets completely messed up (assuming I've selected teachers within at least some of the classrooms). After some experimenting, it almost seems like adding a teacher to a classroom via the Entity Reference field creates a duplicate of the classroom, so then in my aggregated view, the # of students gets over-counted.

In other words, if I have school A and classrooms A1 (10 students) and A2 (10 students) and no teachers in either classroom, it will show me school A has two classrooms, 20 students and 0 teachers. If I add two teachers to A1 and 2 teachers to A2, though, I suddenly have four classrooms, # of students will then jump to 40 and the # of teachers will be 4 (which is right).

I am at my wits end on how to fix this, or why it's even happening. Any ideas? It's really hard to explain.

Comment: I actually know the exact situation you are experiencing. However, to steer you towards a fix I would need to see screen shots of the view that works, and then the view that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you adding teachers as a field or as a relation?  A relation translates into a SQL JOIN, which can lead to exactly the sort of duplication you describe.

Comment: @Brandon Bearden -- good to hear! Here's a screenshot of the view that works (note: I call my "teachers" mentors): http://screencast.com/t/ykE6bkmY3bA; but when i add the "mentors" field, the student count breaks: http://screencast.com/t/LJqwSkZ6DD5O. Any ideas?

Comment: Your aggregation is doubling in your example because it is not grouping by classroom. It is counting each classroom/teacher pair as a unique unit. This is an effect of the Entity Reference you have setup. It is like a foreach. You are asking: foreach classroom and teacher, what is the student count? I can't create a solution from the theory of this setup. I would have to see it and tinker a bit to get it figured out. One suggestion would be to make the classroom a reference to the mentor and count it in reverse. Another would be to fiddle with the aggregation settings.

Comment: did you arrive at a solution?